# Remove variance from temporal observations (input to HMM emission) by manipulating the individual observations

Tags: hidden-markov-model, discrete-data, threshold

I have 52 weekly observations of count data that has some spikes and a definite trend (available [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/37488982/obs-per-week.csv)).

```
obs.pw <- read.csv(paste0(download.path,'obs-per-week.csv'))
obs.pw <- obs.pw[ 2:dim(obs.pw)[2]]
```

The mean weekly values calculated as such (can't post images yet):

```
plot(colMeans(obs.pw), xlab="Weeks", ylab="Mean Counts")
```

The weekly observations (8976 users per week) follow a zero-inflated negative binomial distribution. They are generally about 95% zeros.

The summary data for the column sums of this data:

```
summary(colSums(obs.pw))
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
853    1424    1567    1607    1770    2374
```

Although the spikes and trend information is interesting it is not what I am interested in exploring now.

I am **trying to the segment the non-zero counts for users into different ranges based on how infrequent that observation is**. I want to transform each observed integer count into ordinal categorical variables. Example variables would be: low, medium or high.

A threshold is set for each category and the value is greater than or equal to the threshold the observation is assigned to that category (e.g. if(obs >= 30) cat.obs <- medium). The categories would ideally divide different quantiles of the data.

The problem with the spread of points and trend highlighted in the graph means that **these thresholds are time dependent**. I am using these categorical variables as input to a Hidden Markov Model and want an observation to be just as rare on week 1 as week 50.

I have tried dividing each individual observation by the mean observation count for that week but this line still seems to have a trend.

Is there a way to scale these observations with the given mean data, or otherwise so that a threshold on day 1 for a low,med,high observation is roughly the same as for week 50?

Or is this the wrong approach entirely?